# How can I use aggregate to calculate the average of a number of rows of a dataset?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataset that looks something like this

```
yr<-c(2009, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2005, 2005, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2003)

Na<-runif(17, 20.0, 3.0)
NH4<- runif(17, 0.0, 1.0)
Ca<- runif(17, 1.0, 15.0)

dd<- data.frame(yr, Na, NH4, Ca)
```

with the mean difference that the real dataset is 3500 rows long so doing this thing by hand is a bit of a problem. 
I need to create a new dataset with the annual average (and average every 5 and 10 years)... I tried to use aggregate with a basic code from a tutorial but it didn't work... 
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

For calculating the average by year, you can use functions from the `dplyr` package:

```
dd %>% 
    group_by(yr) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), mean)

# A tibble: 7 x 4
     yr    Na   NH4    Ca
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2003 11.6  0.247  3.80
2  2004 11.9  0.323  8.69
3  2005  5.21 0.512 12.9 
4  2006 13.1  0.312  5.68
5  2007 14.8  0.645  7.83
6  2008 11.1  0.479  7.72
7  2009  4.66 0.444 12.3
```

Or For intervals of years, try the `cut` function:

```
dd %>% 
    mutate(yr2 = cut(yr, breaks = c(2000, 2005, 2010))) %>% 
    group_by(yr2) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(-group_cols(), -yr), mean)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  yr2            Na   NH4    Ca
  <fct>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 (2000,2005]  9.60 0.373  9.27
2 (2005,2010] 12.0  0.476  7.61
```

Comment: the problem with this cut, I think... is that the real dataset goes as far as the year 1200... is there another way to aggregate them by groups of 5 years?

Comment: Why not just use `cut(yr, breaks = seq(from = 1200, to = 2020, by = 5)`?